# Testing elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I have searched for a simple way to check ,

if any number of elements up to 6 in the array add up to seven. I have yet to find one my array is this,

```
private int[] diceRoll = new int[6];
```

Comment: Means it can be up to 6 numbers adding to 7 ?

Comment: It sounds like he wants to know what subsets of diceRoll will add up to 7. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, however, here's my attempt at an answer:
If what you're trying to do is take two indices x and y in diceRoll[] and see if they add up to 7, the simplest thing to do is

```
if(diceRoll[x] + diceRoll[y] ==7){
return true;}
```

If you're trying to see if ANY item with any other item adds up to 7, use a double for-loop (these are weird, but very helpful)

```
    for(int i = 0; i < diceRoll.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; i < diceRoll.length; i++){
    if(diceRoll[i] + diceRoll[j] != 7){
    return false;
    }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

-katie

Comment: Yes like all 6 of them or any number of them

Comment: The second `for` loop should read `for(int j = 0; j < diceRoll.length; j++){`

Comment: @Josh.O  This is assuming that there will only be two dice rolls every time.  What if there are 3 or 4? See my answer for a way to find every possible combination of dice roll of any amount of rolls, that will add up to 7

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to do is take every subset of the diceRoll array and see which ones add up to 7.  This is how it can be done.

Assuming you know that 1 & 1 = 1, and that 1 & 0 = 0, imagine each element of the array having a number in 0 0 0 0 0, if the element is selected, say element 5, the subset representation in binary form would be 0 0 0 0 1. If element 2 and 3 are selected, the subset representation would be 0 0 1 1 0.  If you take a binary one, keep track of its index, and move it from right to left in the array computing index&1 each time, you can get which indexes of the array are in the current subset (if the index&1 computation results in a 1 for that index).  Translating this to a smaller array called currSubset, you can sum it up and check if it is equal to 7.

The termination of the outer for loop comes from the maximum value of a 5 digit binary number, which is 11111 = 31 = 2^5-1, hence the use of the less than sign.

```
int sum = 0;
int index = 0;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsetsThatAddTo7 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(int subsetRep = 0b00001; i < Math.pow(2,5); i++){
    ArrayList<Integer> currSubset = new ArrayList<Integer>
    for(index = 0; index < 5; index++){
        if(subsetRep & (1 << index))
            currSubset.add(diceRoll[5-index]);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for(int num : currSubset)
        sum += num;
    if(sum == 7)
        subsetsThatAddTo7.add(currSubset);
}
```